# Facted Search using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search, faceted-search

I'm trying to implementing faceted search in a Jewellery store, but failed. Problem is when try to filter the attributes table. structure is as follows:

Products Table:

```
Id Product_Code Product_Name
1  ABCGOLD1GM   1 gm Gold
2  ABCGOLD2GM   2 gm Gold
3  ABCGOLD394   3.94 gm Gold
```

Attributes Table:

```
Id   Attr_Name   Alias
1    Metal       metal
2    Fineness    fineness
3    Weight      weight
```

Product_Attributes Table:

```
id    product_id    attr_id   value
1         1            2      9999
2         1            3      1 gm
3         2            2      9999
4         2            3      2 gm
5         3            3      3.94 gm
6         3            2      9167
```

Now i want to filter if someone selects 1 gm with 999 and 3.94 gm. If you know faceted search then you can easily know what i mean. I want to make query to do the same with the table structure above.

Comment: Show the queries you have now and what you have tried.  Am I correct in that you are trying to filter the column `value` by multiple values?

Comment: I used the below query but it gives only for 2 gm with 9999 but when i'm selecting 1 gm also it gives no results

select * from `product_attributes` where (`attr_id` = 4 and `text` = 2 gms) or (`attr_id` = 2 and `text` = 9999) group by `product_id` having count(*) = 2

Comment: I used the below query but it gives only for 2 gm with 9999 but when i'm selecting 1 gm also it gives no results
select * from product_attributes where (attr_id = 4 and value = 2 gms) or (attr_id = 2 and value = 9999) group by product_id having count(*) = 2